# Wordpress Search Results in Order

Tags: php, search, wordpress, e-commerce, shopp

One of my clients websites, www.kevinsplants.co.uk is not showing the search results in alphabetical order, how do I go about ordering the results in alphabetical order?

We are using the Shopp plugin and I believe its that plugin that is generating the results!

Cheers, Brad

```
case "orderby-list":
            if (isset($Shopp->Category->controls)) return false;
            if (isset($Shopp->Category->smart)) return false;
            $menuoptions = Category::sortoptions();
            $title = "";
            $string = "";
            $default = $Shopp->Settings->get('default_product_order');
            if (empty($default)) $default = "title";

            if (isset($options['default'])) $default = $options['default'];
            if (isset($options['title'])) $title = $options['title'];

            if (value_is_true($options['dropdown'])) {
                if (isset($Shopp->Cart->data->Category['orderby'])) 
                    $default = $Shopp->Cart->data->Category['orderby'];
                $string .= $title;
                $string .= '<form action="'.esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'" method="get" id="shopp-'.$Shopp->Category->slug.'-orderby-menu">';
                if (!SHOPP_PERMALINKS) {
                    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
                        if ($key != 'shopp_orderby') $string .= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" />';
                }
                $string .= '<select name="shopp_orderby" class="shopp-orderby-menu">';
                $string .= menuoptions($menuoptions,$default,true);
                $string .= '</select>';
                $string .= '</form>';
                $string .= '<script type="text/javascript">';
                $string .= "jQuery('#shopp-".$Shopp->Category->slug."-orderby-menu select.shopp-orderby-menu').change(function () { this.form.submit(); });";
                $string .= '</script>';
            } else {
                if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"?") !== false) 
                    list($link,$query) = explode("\?",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $query = $_GET;
                unset($query['shopp_orderby']);
                $query = http_build_query($query);
                if (!empty($query)) $query .= '&';

                foreach($menuoptions as $value => $option) {
                    $label = $option;
                    $href = esc_url($link.'?'.$query.'shopp_orderby='.$value);
                    $string .= '<li><a href="'.$href.'">'.$label.'</a></li>';
                }

            }
            return $string;
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sort-searchresult-by-title/

This is a plug-in that seems to do what you want.

Comment: I installed it and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the template file of the search page and add to the search query parameters `orderby title`, as opposed to the default ordering which is by time of publication

Comment: Can you give me further details on how to do that please?

Comment: Sure. I assume you have access to the theme files in `wp-content\themes\[yourTheme]`. Look through them and find the one which presents the search results. Paste the code in your question and I'll try to help. It seems like it's in `index.php`

Comment: Well it uses an ecommerce plugin, so I'm unsure!

Comment: I have updated the post with the code I think its in search.php

Comment: I don't think so. Your template should have "No products were found". Try to run a search across files. even if the syntax is dynamically generated via a plugin, it is still written as open-source, and can be modified. Check the `wp-content/plugins` directory

Comment: Im struggling to find a page! grr

Comment: You found the file. Now trace the `shopp` function, which is clearly responsible for the order: `shopp('catalog','orderby-list','dropdown=on');`

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to edit the core code. And lucky for you it is not necessary. You can edit/create your own template file collection-search.php and style it any way you want.

There is more info on template files [here](https://shopplugin.net/workshopp/shopp-content-templates-visual-guide/).